# std::greater<int>() expected 0 arguments (or 1 arguments), 2 provided, why?

Tags: c++, stl

This is defined in STL header file:

```
template<typename _Tp>
    struct greater : public binary_function<_Tp, _Tp, bool>
    {
      bool
      operator()(const _Tp& __x, const _Tp& __y) const
      { return __x > __y; }
    };
```

I wrote just one line simple code as below:

```
cout << (std::greater<int>(3, 2)? "TRUE":"FALSE") << endl;
```

It does not compile.  Error message is:

```
C:\Qt\Tools\mingw482_32\i686-w64-mingw32\include\c++\bits\stl_function.h:222: std::greater<int>::greater()
     struct greater : public binary_function<_Tp, _Tp, bool>
            ^
C:\Qt\Tools\mingw482_32\i686-w64-mingw32\include\c++\bits\stl_function.h:222: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 2 provided
C:\Qt\Tools\mingw482_32\i686-w64-mingw32\include\c++\bits\stl_function.h:222: std::greater<int>::greater(const std::greater<int>&)
C:\Qt\Tools\mingw482_32\i686-w64-mingw32\include\c++\bits\stl_function.h:222: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
```

What's wrong?
The compiler is, of course, minGW (GCC).

It's a simplified version of my codes.  In fact, I am using std::greater in my complicated sorting algorithm.

Comment: You're trying to construct an object with 2 parameters, but that class has no constructor...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::greater<...>` is a class, not a function. This class have overloaded `operator()`, but you need an object of the class to call that operator upon. So you should create an instance of the class, then call it:

```
cout << (std::greater<int>()(3, 2)? "TRUE":"FALSE") << endl;
//                        #1  #2
```

Here the first pair of parentheses (`#1`) creates an instance of `std::greater<int>`, and `#2` calls `std::greater<int>::operator()(const int&, const int&)`.

Comment: It's a class, but it has a `()` operator receiving 2 arguments.  The class name itself acts as a functor.

Comment: Another words: why can std::sort() use std::greater<int>() as its last argument?  I want to create some function like that.

Comment: @RobinHsu so create a class/struct and overload `operator()`.

Comment: @RobinHsu: No, an instance of the class acts as a functor. The class name itself is used to create an instance `greater()`, which can then be called like a function, `greater()(3,2)`.

Comment: @RobinHsu I've made my answer as clear as I can, check it out

Answer (score 0):

`std::greater` is a class template, not a function template. The expression `std::greater<int>(3,2)` attempts to call a constructor of `std::greater<int>` taking two ints.

You need to create an instance of it, then use `operator()` on it:

```
cout << (std::greater<int>{}(3, 2)? "TRUE":"FALSE") << endl;
```